# Does AMQP Version 1.0 support Publish/Subscribe Pattern?

Tags: publish-subscribe, amqp

I am a bit confused about the AMQP 1.0 specification.
In versions prior to 1.0 there were a lot of details about the message broker itself. In version 1.0 - as i understand - are no details about the message broker or even the existence of a message broker. Using the exchanges of AMQP prior to 1.0 multiple messaging patterns were possible to configure.
Does AMQP 1.0 still specify multiple patterns?

(I am especially interested in Publish/Subscribe)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMQP 1.0 doesn't include broker details because it's possible to use AMQP point to point without a broker in AMQP 1.0. You certainly can still use a broker (or more than one) but it's not required like it was prior to 1.0.

Yes, multiple patterns, including pub-sub, are supported. Of course, the terminology and mechanics of how it happens "under the covers" is all different. However, if you use a higher level API to access pub-sub features on AMQP pre-1.0 you can probably just continue to use the same API.